# ASP.NET Core link from an other site -> Identity null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core website with these settings:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict });
```

Login cookie:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { AllowRefresh = true };
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

Everything works well, `@User.Identity.Name` gives my email address.
The problem is if I create a html file on my desktop and add this into it:

```
<a href="https://localhost:44315/">link text</a>
```

After click the link I got moved to the site but `@User.Identity.Name` gives nothing. After refresh the site (not with F5) it works again.

What can cause this?

Comment: It depends on the code in that serves `https://localhost:44315/`. In other words, what code do you have in the controller for that request?

Comment: If I change SameSiteMode.Strict To SameSiteMode.Unspecified it works well. Do you know why?

Comment: SameSiteMode.Lax works well too.

Comment: this looks like a wrong assumption, do you open your local html file in the same browser as what used to open your web & login before? I don't see any kind of security-related issue here. Your local html file is just a static local page, any external links on it can be visited just like when you type the URL exactly in the browser's address bar.